# Why does not the Euclidean space support a countably additive measure defined for all subsets?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The three axioms that a measure function $m$ need satisfy are as follows. Let the word "measure" mean the value returned by this measure function, $m$ defined on a set in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

1. The measure of an interval $I$ is its length: $m(I)= l(I)$;
2. The measure is translation invariant: $m(E+y) = m(E)$;
3. The measure is countably additive over countable disjoint union of sets: $$m(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} m(E_k)$$.

My questions are: **Why cannot a set function be defined that satisfy all the above? What is the geometry or structure of $\mathbb{R^n}$ that prevents this from happening?**

Considering $\mathbb{R^n}$ is complete, totally ordered, it seems like a space that is not pathological at all, yet it harbors this problem when comes to measure. Could someone explain why? Thank you.

Also, even though existence of a non-measurable set can be shown, can one be actually constructed?

Comment: [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set)

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is *not* totally ordered . . .

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\mathbb{R}$; I copy-pasted. Sorry.

Comment: First,  you talk about intervals and length of interval,  so the Euclidean spaces you mean are actually just $\mathbb{R}$? 

Second, the conditions you wrotre are not the general definition of measure. There are several measures in the Euclidean space (and in $\mathbb{R}$) which does not coincide with the lenght on intervals and  / or are not translation invariant. 

Third, there are several measures in the Euclidean space (and in $\mathbb{R}$) which are defined on all subsets (of course they do not coincide with the lenght on intervals and  they are not translation invariant).